# Eager Loading mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

I want optimize this code with mongoid **eager loading** if it's possible. This is the first code that is working fine:

```
orders_with_user_detail = Order.where(cv_id: current_user.cv.id)
orders_with_user_detail.each do |order|
  Order.delay(queue: "order", priority: 2, run_at: order.end_at).delete_user_details(order)
end
```

I want make only 1 query to my database if it's possible with something like:

```
Mongoid.identity_map_enabled = true
User.includes(:orders).each do |order|
  Order.delay(queue: "order", priority: 2, run_at: order.end_at).delete_user_details(order)
end
```

**How can I get all orders where `cv_id` is the `current_user.cv_id` with eager loading?**

**Is it possible for this code?**

Thank you very much!

Comment: mongoid eager loads everything